# How to center the title based on the viewport width (css3)

Tags: html, css

I have this situation in which I have a header with on the left a logo and on the right some user info (like an avatar). Important to understand is that the width of the logo and the user element are not the same!

So, in the middle of the header I have a title, something like this:

```
<header>
    <img class="logo" src="http://file.png">
    <div class="user"> </div> 

    <h1>This is the title</h1>
</header>
```

I have create a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jeanluca/3hy4nnqy/)

Although this header works great if you resize the area (with ellipses), however, the title is not in the middle of the screen/viewport.

So the question is, considering the behaviour when resizing, is it possible to center the title based on the viewport width ?

UPDATE: Based on the work done by Hassan Ahmad (see below) I've updated the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jeanluca/3hy4nnqy/2/). This is exactly what I need, but as mentioned already, the media query makes this solution a bit hacky. Any suggestions how to achieve the same without a media query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this css:

```
header {
    position: relative;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    text-align: center;
}

.logo {
    position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;
    height: 50px;
    width: 300px;
}

.user {
    position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;

}
```

**edit:**

```
h1 {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    margin-right: 50px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 820px){
    .logo { position: static; float: left; }
}
```

Comment: What you've done here is center the h1 with respect to the viewport, which is what I want, except that now the ellipses doesn't work anymore

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by "ellipses don't work"? I am a little confused here.

Comment: If you take my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeanluca/3hy4nnqy/) and you make the viewport smaller the title will get an ellipses (three dots at the end)

Comment: Yes but what do you really want to appear? Do you want to hide either the logo or text when it's resized? because there won't be enough space for both.

Comment: I want the title to get smaller and smaller. The logo and user element have a fixed width

Comment: yep thats it, however this looks to me like a hack. If no other solutions (without media queries) are given, I'll check this answer as the correct one, thnx a lot!